# Question Is it possible to take a list of numbers and put each one of them in a different cell

Tags: excel

I have a lot of data sequences I need to statistically analyze.
The problem is that the numbers are separated by a space character.
I need each number to be in a different excel cell.
Is there a way to tell excel to use the space as "move the next number to a different cell"?

For example:
1 2 3 4 
needs to go to 4 cells:
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

If i just do copy paste, excel (obviously) puts all the numbers in the same cell:
| 1 2 3 4 |

Which is not what i need..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use "Text to Columns":

Go to "Data" -> "Text to Columns". In the window that pop-up choose "Delimited". Then click "Next >".

[image]

Choose "Space" as your delimiter. Click "Finish".

[image]

The result is that Excel converts all the cells with values if they are separated by a space to individual cells.

[image]